# How to change opencv reference path

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have been troubling with changing version of opencv. I deleted old version of it for some reason and installed new version follow this site:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html
my cmake parameters are as follows:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/robotics/opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

and now I realized that I can not catkin_make. the error message is below:

> CMake Error at /usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake:179 (message):
> The imported target "opencv_core" references the file
>
> ```
>  "/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1"
> ```
>
> but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
>
> - The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
> - An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
> - The installation package was faulty and contained
>
>   "/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake"
>
> but not all the files it references.

I think the problem is that cmake is still searching old version of opencv I installed by package, but I don't know how to change that path to new opencv I installed is any idea can allow me to edit this path? Or any way to install opencv with path set correctly? Thank you!

Comment: It seems you forgot to remove file `/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake` when removed your old OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you said I reinstalled opencv again after removed the whole folder(/usr/share/OpenCV), and now comes another error message: "Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "10.0", but required is exact
  version "10.2" (found /usr/local/cuda)" that is from another program. I think opencv problem is sloved but I still don't understand: after reinstalling and reboot, this folder doesn't show up again and I'm using opencv without this whole folder. What is this folder actually do and how to generate it at the first time?

Comment: The directory `/usr/share/OpenCV` and files in it are part of OpenCV installation. It should appear when you install OpenCV globally.

Comment: So is it ok to use opencv without this folder? And can I install opencv globally using cmake and make install? I think its better have it even I only have 1 user in this computer.